# Ubuntu 14.04 nvidia setting empty

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-settings

I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 in Apr using official repository nvidia-331.38 driver. I just noticed a few days ago that the nvidia-setting screen is basically empty, no advance settings I can see, screenshot attached.

I remember I saw this screen before (other driver versions in 13.10 and earlier) that had a number of advance settings.

Is my driver installation corrupted?
Does anyone know how to enable the advance settings?

Thanks!

[image: nvidia-setting-empty]

Comment: Are there any errors shown when you start the application in a Terminal? (The command is `nvidia-settings`)

Comment: I just tried and got below two lines error in Terminal,
    `** Message: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort`
    `** Message: PRIME: is it supported? no`

Something wrong with my nvidia driver installation?

Comment: At least it's not indicated by those messages, I get the same, but I have more settings...

Comment: You could try to install the 304.177 driver (using the program 'Additional Drivers'). As far as I can remember I couldn't observe that my graphics card became much faster when I upgraded my drivers to the latest version anyway...